How to migrate to Svelte 5.0.0?
I have been running a pre-release of Svelte 5 as described in the package.json below.
How do I migrate from 5.0.0-next.150 to the new Svelte 5.0.0 release?
Below is my package.json
"devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^5.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^24.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.77.4",
    "svelte": "^5.0.0-next.150",
    "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.1.4",
    "svelte-range-slider-pips": "^2.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.3",
    "vitest": "^2.0.5"
},


All I did was install Svelte 5.0.0 and move files across. A few npm packages had to be reinstalled. To be honest this is preferred as its cleaner for me.

I don't think there is a migration script from pre-release to release version, though you can try running the migration intended to migrate from Svelte 4.
npx sv migrate svelte-5

Migrating from a pre-release version should not require that many changes; worst case scenario you have to go though all the in-between releases and check for changes marked as breaking: and handle them accordingly.
The official migration guide can be found here.

official migration guide will be released soon, preview is available at: https://svelte-omnisite.vercel.app/docs/svelte/v5-migration-guide

First remove svelte and @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte:
npm r svelte @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte

Then install the latest versions:
npm i svelte @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte -D

